# upload an image to firebase storage

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I uploaded the image put I can't see it in firebase storage

```
Future uploadPic(BuildContext context) async {
    String fileName = basename(_image.path);
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image);
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;

    setState(() {
        print("Profile picture uploaded");
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Profile picture uploaded')));
    });
}
```

Comment: What does this return `await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();`?

Comment: Local variable 'taskSnapshot' cant be referenced before it is declared

Comment: Please use it before your `setState` callback.

Comment: Reformatted code for readability

Comment: #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)
#1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      StorageReference.getDownloadURL (package:firebase_storage/src/storage_reference.dart:142:42)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      EditProfileState.build.uploadPic (package:car_app_firebase_03/UI/edit_profile_page.dart:38:30)
<asynchronous suspension>

Comment: #4      EditProfileState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:car_app_firebase_03/UI/edit_profile_page.dart:107:32)
#5      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:635:14)
#6      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure><…>

Comment: and this is the submit button ,  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      uploadPic(context);
                    },